# AttributeError: Y instance has no attribute 'X'

Tags: python, oop, attributeerror

I'm new to Python OOP, and I'm building a Blackjack game to improve my understanding and implementation of OO Python.

Here's what I have written so far for my Deck and Card classes:

```
import random

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        # init variables
        self.cards = []
        self.numCards = 0
        self.populate_cards()

    def deal(self):
        return self.cards.pop(random.randint(0, (self.numCards - 1)))

    def populate_cards(self):
        for suit in range (0, 5):
            for face in range (0, 13):
                card = Card(face, suit)
                self.cards.append(card)
                self.numCards = self.numCards + 1

    def cards_left(self):
        print (self.numCards)
        print (self.cards)

class Card:
    def __init__(self, face = 0, suit = 0):
        self.face = face
        self.suit = suit

    def assign_value_using_face(self):
        pass
```

When I execute the Python prompt, I will try to create an instance of Deck after importing the Cards.py file into Python.

```
>>> from Cards import *
>>> deck = Deck()
```

However, I keep receiving an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Cards.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.populate_cards()
AttributeError: Deck instance has no attribute 'populate_cards'
```

I looked around on Stackoverflow and all the cases where this error occurred weren't properly using the "self." in front of populate_cards(), or weren't passing the "self" argument to populate_cards, both of which I am doing.  Can someone please help?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code runs without errors for me, and I can successfully do `Deck()`.

Comment: Check for mixed tabs and spaces, and check for indentation problems in general. Also, check your spelling, and if you have `Cards.py` open in an editor, save it.

Comment: Also, note that `deal` isn't properly adjusting `self.numCards`. Why not just use `len(self.cards)` instead of having an extra variable you need to remember to change every time `self.cards` changes?

Comment: @BrenBarn Which version of Python are you running?  I'm running 2.7.3

Comment: @user2357112 I just checked by exposing all the hidden characters using my VIM editor - There are no tabs, and all spacing is consistent

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the len() tip!  I'll implement into my code

Comment: I'm using 2.7.5, but I doubt this is a version problem.  Is it possible you're not loading the file you think you are (i.e., an old version is being run)?  Also note that if you once import your module, importing it again will have no effect.  You need to use `reload` (or restart the interpreter) to see the effect of changes made to the module.

Comment: Note that `reload` does a lot less than you might expect. `from` imports need to be rerun manually, instances of the old versions of classes don't automatically update to the new version, etc. It can be useful, but getting it to do what you want can be a hassle.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me too (Python 3.3.5 IDLE)

Comment: Odd...  I'm developing on my Raspberry Pi, do you think that could be an issue?  I'll move my code to my Linux box and see if it works on there.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: So I tried my code again on 2 different devices, and I keep encountering the same error.  My Linux box was running Ubuntu with Python 2.7.3 and my work laptop is running Python 2.6.